# IdentityServer4 Add Password returns false

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity

I tried to change the password of a user in .NET Core.

I am using `RemovePasswordAsync` and `AddPasswordAsync` methods. But i get an error

> User name 'ÖK00433' is invalid, can only contain letters or digits."

```
var password = GenerateRandomPassword();

//my user - ÖK00433
var item = await _userManager.Users.Where(p => p.UserName == usernameForPwd).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

await _userManager.RemovePasswordAsync(item);

// result.Succeeded is false here
var result = await _userManager.AddPasswordAsync(item, password);
```

I expect the result to be true and successfully updated new password.

Comment: The error message is very clear.  It doesn't understand the "O" with the accent.  Try a different username with alphanumeric character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a language origin character problem, you should consider using  Latin letters.